# Define type of parameters of an object passed as argument in typescript without knowing the name of the parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a function which requires an object as argument.
All parameters of this object should follow rules defined by an interface. How can I define that?

Example code:

```
interface Fruit {
    color: string;
    weight: number;
}

function printFruits(fruits) {
   for (fruit in fruits) {
      print(fruit + ' is ' + fruits[fruit].color)
   }
}
```

So `fruits` argument will be something like that:

```
{
   banana: {color: 'yellow', weight: '0.1'},
   apple: {color: 'red', weight: '0.5'},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is:

```
function printFruits(fruits: { [name: string]: Fruit }) {
   for (fruit in fruits) {
      print(fruit + ' is ' + fruits[fruit].color)
   }
}
```

You can also have a type alias for it:

```
type Fruits = { [name: string]: Fruit };

function printFruits(fruits: Fruits) {
   for (fruit in fruits) {
      print(fruit + ' is ' + fruits[fruit].color)
   }
}
```